# Constructing a one-sided hypothesis test for joint probabilties of negative binomial distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictive-models, biostatistics, negative-binomial-distribution, likelihood-ratio

I am conducting research on Codling moth population/trap capture models. The end goal is to have a hypothesis testing model that will provide whether or not (at some significance level $\alpha$) the data supports the total number of moth captures for the generation to be above a certain threshold. The growers that I work with, through experience, are able to set a "maximum tolerable threshold" for the total number of captures. They may know through their experience that years where they capture greater than 700 moths need to have pesticides applied, whereas years with less than that value do not.

First, I have a Johnson-SB distribution model (gathered through previous years data) that lays out the expected proportion of the total moth captures for a given amount of heat accumulation (essentially time). Put in simpler words, I have a CDF that tells me at some time $x$ I would, on average, expect to have captured $y$ percent of the total number of moths I will ever capture. I can then multiply this distribution by some maximum value to get an expectation for the concrete number of moths I will observe in my traps. For example, if the total number of moths I will capture is 700, then at time $x=150$ I will expect to observe a cumulative capture of $y=42$ moths. This allows me to calculate an expected cumulative capture value $\overline{y}_x$ for any amount of heat accumulation $x$.

Second, while the Johnson-SB model lays out the expected value, there is a negative binomial model that lays out the probability density for actually observing a given number of cumulative moths for some expected value. For example, while I *expect* to capture $y=42$ moths at $x=150$, I may actually only capture $y=30$, or $y=60$, etc., and the negative binomial model allows me to construct the PDF for a given expected value.

Third, I have a set of $n$ observations on heat accumulation and cumulative captures, which I'll call $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

My initial idea was to just create a joint probability for if the true expected values for the set $X$, which I will notate $\mu_x$, are less than the model expectations $\overline{y}_x$:
$$ \prod\limits_{i=1}^n P[Y_i | \mu_{X_i}\le \overline{y}_{X_i}]$$
Where the probability of observing $Y_i$ if the true expected value is less than the model expectation is calculated using the CDF of the negative binomial distributions specified above. This is my null distribution.

This has the issue, however, that because it is a joint distribution, it always grows smaller as I add new observations, as I am essentially asking the probability of an increasingly specific scenario. Therefore I need to find some way of normalizing this joint probability. My idea was to create a ratio of the null distribution and it's complement, which I believe would be:

$$ \frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n P[Y_i | \mu_{X_i}\le \overline{y}_{X_i}]}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n 1-P[X_i | \mu_{Y_i}\le \overline{y}_{X_i}]}$$
But I am lost on how I can evaluate this ratio, either by a rejection region or a p-value. I have looked into likelihood ratio tests and read through [this](https://www.jclinepi.com/article/S0895-4356(21)00132-3/fulltext) page and [this](http://people.missouristate.edu/songfengzheng/Teaching/MTH541/Lecture%20notes/LRT.pdf) document, but I feel I am lacking the understanding for it to click with me on how exactly I would go about using this methodology (if I even should) to my problem.

Do you believe that I am on the right track with the methods I'm currently using to solve this problem, and if so, how would I go about interpreting the ratio to help my growers make informed management decisions?

Comment: Are your $n$ observations a time series, in the sense that $y_i = y_{i-1} + \delta_i$ and $\delta_i$ is the number of captures between when $x_{i-1}$ and $x_i$ were measured?  Or are they completely independent samples?

Comment: @jbowman Yes they are time series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to figure out how to do this using an iterative Bayesian approach like so:

$$
P[N \ge H_0 | X] = \frac{
\int_{\hat{x}}^{\infty}\prod_i P[x_i|N=H_0]dH_0 * P[N \ge H_0]
}{
\int_{0}^{\hat{x}}\prod_i P[x_i|N=H_0]dH_0 * (1-P[N \ge H_0]) + \int_{\hat{x}}^{\infty}\prod_i P[x_i|N=H_0]dH_0 * P[N \ge H_0]
}
$$
Where
$$
P[x|N=H_0]: \text{PDF of Neg Bin with parameters determined with Johnson-SB model} \\
P[N\ge H_0]: \text{prior probability} \\
P[N \ge H_0 | x]: \text{posterior probability}
$$

Starting with a prior of 0.5, and then using the posterior of the last data point as the prior for the next data point.